Can not center align button in mailchimp form
I am working on form to add mailchimp basic subscription form to footer and can not find how to align button to subscribe to the center of form. Please help, I tired everything.
It very simple looking form, but button always move to right and not staying in the center. At one stage I made it work, but then accidently change something and now I can not get button back in the center. So it just one line in css something i change, i just can not remember what. I tried so many times and i can not find what it is. Stress me out. Thank you for helping.
Here is css:
/* mc footer form */
#footermc-div {
  height: 350px;
    padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0c94dd, #2e3192);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
#mc_embed_signup {
    background: transparent;
    min-width: 600px;
}
#mc_embed_signup form {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center !important;
}
#mc_embed_signup label {
  color: white; 
  min-width: 450px;
  display: block;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
#mc_embed_signup input {
  color: #999999; 
}
#mc_embed_signup h2 {
  color: white; 
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
}
#mc-embedded-subscribe {
  background-color: #2e3192 !important;
  color: white !important;
  border: 1px solid white !important;
  border-radius: 30px !important;
  padding: 10px 20px!important;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
}
#mc-embedded-subscribe:hover {
  background-color: #0c94dd !important;
}
#mce-success-response {
  display: block;  
  text-align: center; 
  color: white !important;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) { 
  #footermc-div {
    height: auto;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  #mc_embed_signup {
    min-width: 90%;
  }
}


CSS without the HTML it is supposed to apply to, tells us rather little. Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue, wen asking this kind of question.
